# python: how to use 'import' on character string variable?

Tags: python, import

I want to create a function which uses import, like the following:

```
    def test_module(module_name):
            try:
                    import module_name
            except ImportError:
                    print 'import '+module_name+' error'


    test_module('os')
```

however, the function doesn't work because import seems not to recognize the string variable.
are there any workarounds?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imported = __import__(module_name)` will work.

Or you can use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

The difference is in convenience: in case of import like 
`module_name = 'top.lower'`

`__import__`  will return `top`, whereas `importlib.import_module` will return `lower`:

```
>>> __import__('os.path')
<module 'os' from nowhere>
>>> importlib.import_module('os.path')
<module 'ntpath' from nowhere>
```

Comment: (I did not downvote).  Your syntax is wrong.  It should be `imported = __import__(module_name)`.  That said, the preferred method is to use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).